# Create an alias for "pipe grep"

Tags: grep, zsh, aliases

I would like to create an alias for `| grep`

eg, for example be able to write:

`ps -axf G chrome` instead of `ps -axf | grep chrome`

I've written the following in my aliases file of oh-my-zsh:

`alias -g G= '| grep --color'`

However, this doesn's seem to work.

Any idea why ?

**EDIT**

I get the following error when I write `ps -axf G chrome`

```
error: must set personality to get -x option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

It seems that the `G` is interpreted as being part of the ps command

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is vague. What exactly happens when you try to use the alias? Do other aliases in the same file work properly?

Comment: What's `-g` option for?

Comment: It means to set the alias globally. I thought that would help, but it's exactly the same if I use it or if I don't

Comment: I see it's actually for Zsh sorry.

Comment: It is the ps that is failing try it without the grep

Comment: The same question but for fish asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821056/fish-create-an-alias-for-pipe-grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alias` statement can't have space between assignment:

```
alias -g G='| grep --color'
```

Comment: Do you know how to achieve that in fish-shell?

Comment: @xliiv fish doesn't seem to have real aliases, only functions; so it's likely not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I have

```
alias -g G=' | grep -i '
```

so the syntax seems OK

so I can do :-

```
cat file.txt G fred
```

are you actually running zsh (echo $SHELL)

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives back `/usr/bin/zsh`