# Fish: Create an alias for "pipe grep"

Tags: grep, fish

I would like to create an alias for `| grep`

eg, for example be able to write:

`ps -axf G chrome` instead of `ps -axf | grep chrome`

This question was already asked on stackoverflow, however in the context of other shells, like [zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776055/create-an-alias-for-pipe-grep). Proposed solutions like

```
alias -g G=' | grep -i '
```

do not work with fish.

Error message for example given above:

```
- (line 1): Missing end to balance this function definition
function G --wraps ' | grep --color' --description 'alias G= | grep --color';   | grep --color $argv; end
^
from sourcing file -
    called on line 70 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.5.1/share/fish/functions/alias.fish
in function 'alias' with arguments 'G=\ \|\ grep\ --color'
    called on line 6 of file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
```

and for

```
alias -g G=' \| grep -i '
```

it results in error `cat: G: No such file or directory` (by running `cat file G "chrome"`)

Comment: This isn't possible yet, it will be once [enhanced abbreviations](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/discussions/8854) land.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish Is that a teaser to say it's now being actively worked, or just that it's still on the eventual todo list?  Anxiously awaiting the implementation, but I'm sure you have a lot going on, and I appreciate all that you and the contributors have already done.

Comment: I am actively working on it; it should land in either 3.6 or 3.7 at the latest, depending on the timing of 3.6.

Comment: Do you specifically want to be able to omit the pipe ?  Is this to save typing one character because of its awkward positioning, or is there another advantage conferred by this that makes simply aliasing `grep` itself insufficient?

Comment: @CJK Saving to type pipe | character due to awkward position on the kayboard. I've been using `G` in omz for 7 years now, so it's hard to unlearn muscle memory now :P